# W&B events should trigger CI/CD pipelines in other systems

Tags: continuous-integration, wandb

Weights and Biases offers to setup [triggers](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/models/automation) for certain events such as

- whenever a model artifact is linked to the model registry
- whenever a certain tag is added to a model artifact

However, in the UI one can only trigger W&B internal pipelines. Is it also possible to trigger pipelines in other systems such as gitlab, github, airflow, AWS step functions, etc. ?

Comment: Precisely what you are asking, we have some examples of this type of trigger in this folder: https://github.com/wandb/launch-jobs/tree/main/jobs We are enabling webhooks in the coming months, so it will be even more accessible.